# How can I send array to stored procedure? What is the best data format if I send it from JS?

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

How can I send array to stored procedure?
I want send it from JS to stored procedure. And what is the best data format for this task?

Comment: ok afaik you can use HTML5's Web Database API [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#introduction) to allow the client to interact with a database on the client side. To allow the client to interact with a remote database you would have to implement a server side language such as Java / PHP to act as an intermediary between client and database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL 2008 supports table valued parameters - so you can pass a table of data as a parameter to a sproc. The common ways prior to this, were as mentioned already - via a CSV or XML parameter.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)

Comment: People say that there can be an issue with count of symbols: "There can not be more then 8000 symbols in such string". It is right? Is it a good idea to use CSV instead of XML because of it (it's not supposed to use this string anywhere alse).

Comment: @Anton Not quite sure what you are referring to - 8000 is the largest size you can define for a VARCHAR before you have to VARCHAR(MAX) which supports up to 2GB worth of text. XML datatype supports up to 2GB too. Problem with these is you then have to parse/shred the values out. Hence I'd recommend looking at the table valued parameter approach. I compared the performance of all 3 on my blog here: http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters.html

Comment: One more question. What is better way to do the work: to call sproc with array param or sproc many times one by one in one transaction? Thank you.

Comment: I would pass in a batch and do it in fewer calls, not one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

With MS SQL you should be able to consume it as comma-delimited.

Answer (score 1):

I've used XML to pass arrays of data into SQL server in the past, and it works quite well with XML data types and XQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example using a CSV input parameter to the stored proc.

```
create proc dbo.ListCustomers
(
    @CustomerIDs varchar(MAX)
)
as
begin

-- convert paramter to xml
declare @XmlStr varchar(MAX)
set @XmlStr = '<R><I ID="' + replace(@CustomerIDs, ',', '"></I><I ID="') + '"></I></R>'

-- table variable that holds the ID's
declare @IdTable table (ID int)

-- load the XML document and insert id's to @IdTable
declare @XmlDoc int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @XmlDoc out, @XmlStr
insert into @IdTable select ID from openxml(@XmlDoc, '/R/I',1) with (ID int)
exec sp_xml_removedocument @XmlDoc


-- use @IdTable in your query
select c.*
from tblCustomer c
  join @IdTable as I on c.CustomerID = I.ID 

end
go

-- usage:
-- exec ListCustomers '3823,3838,3845,3925,4051'
```